# Returning IDs from a POST

Tags: angularjs, go, gorest

I've built a web app in angularjs and a service layer using Go and App Engine but I've run into a snag. Angular doesn't seem to recognize the HTTP status 201 (Created) nor the Location header it populates and the [gorest](https://code.google.com/p/gorest/) library that I've been using up until now will not return any body data for a POST or PUT except for the header on a 201 Create response.

I want to be able to add a new item to a collection in my app and have the server respond with the unique ID for it.

I could make a separate GET request after the POST comes back but that's inefficient and messy. I could also fix the gorest code to allow a body in a response for a non GET verb but it might be that I'm breaking idiomatic standards.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There's a closed [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7037) on angular.js's issue tracker, they pretty much don't care about that feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was missing something.

The gorest library automatically marshals the return type from a service method as long as it is a GET. It doesn't allow data to be returned this way with either a POST or PUT.

However I noticed the WriteAndOveride method could allow the body to be set on any type of call:

```
serv.ResponseBuilder().SetResponseCode(200).WriteAndOveride([]byte(responseBody))
```

Whilst it doesn't feel like the cleanest solution, it should certainly unblock me.